# Origin of "turn the other cheek"

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

I’m wondering about the origin of “turn the other cheek”. I have heard it all my life.

Answer (score 1):

From the Bible ...
Matthew 5:38-40 (New International Version)

> You have heard that it was said, ‘Eye for eye, and tooth for tooth.’ But I tell you, do not resist an evil person. If anyone slaps you on the right cheek, turn to them the other cheek also. And if anyone wants to sue you and take your shirt, hand over your coat as well.

Comment: While I want to upvote this because it's the right answer, I feel like I shouldn't, because the question was too easy to answer with a search engine.